# Running Emacs through the value of the bash variable

Tags: bash, emacs, variable

How would I add a value to a new variable in bash, so that when I echo the variable Emacs would run?

Comment: can you clarify what exactly you want/expect, what have you tried and what didn't work for you?

Comment: For example I would like to create a variable EDITOR and than add a value to it, so that with command echo $EDITOR, Emacs would open and I could write something in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make bash to invoke commands during `echo` as far as I know. If I understand well your question you are searching for `alias` keyword.

```
alias editor='emacs'
editor  # will invoke emacs
```

You can store the alias in your `.bashrc` or just edit on-the-fly as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
editor=emacs
$editor          # This will invoke emacs.
```